# How Can I Override Function for Event Handling Without Creating Subclass File in Swift?

Tags: swift, subclass, nsevent

How can I override functions without subclassing?

For example, let's say I want to implement custom mouse drag for different object on a storyboard. Only way I can think of is to:

1. Create subclass for the object and assign it as the custom class using the inspector
2. Override acceptsFirstResponder, mouseDown, mouseDragged, mouseUp in the subclass
3. Execute becomeFirstResponder when someone clicks the object
4. ResignFirstResponder after the action is completed.

Is there way to refer to each object with @IBOutlet in ViewController.swift and override those functions (in step 2) without subclassing every object?

I think delegates or blocks might be used to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to make my own custom delegates/blocks.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!